# Get inner text of nearest parent a tag

Tags: html, css, ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I'm using Ruby & Nokogiri to parse html on a page.

```
<div><a href="#" title="firstTitle">text one</a></div>

  <p class="OK">some content</p>
  <p class="OK">some content</p>

<div><a href="#" title="secondTitle">text two</a></div>

  <p class="WARNING">some content</p>
  <p class="WARNING">some content</p>

<div><a href="#" title="thirdTitle">text three</a></div>

  <p class="CRITICAL">some content</p>
  <p class="CRITICAL">some content</p>
```

Say I want to find paragraphs with a class of `WARNING`, I can do that successfully with:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
warning = doc.css('p.WARNING')
```

But now I want to target the inner text of the nearest parent `a` tag, in this case it would return `text two`.

I've tried using `.first.parent.name` and `previous_element` among other variations but have not been successful and would appreciate some insight. Thanks!

Comment: You could use `previous_element` to work your way backward until you see the `div`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use XPath [`preceding-siblng`](http://zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/Output/example16.html) axis to find specific sibling element before the context element. For example, given the context element is `<p>`, you can try something like the following to get the nearest preceding sibling `div` and then return the corresponding `a` element :

```
link = warning.at_xpath('./preceding-siblng::div[1]/a')
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks promising, as soon as i implement & test I'll accept if successful.